# how do I instantiate database (RoomDB) on app open

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

hey there so i'm having a small design issue where I have a flow of data coming from my RoomDb but when I first open the app the RoomDd does not instantiate till I open the activity where I am using it so this causes me to get a null data object followed by an object with the data. I just wanted to know if there was a way for me to open up my RoomDb as soon as I open my Application

I am using Dagger Hilt for Injection

[output of data on opening activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iAFp.png)

please do let me know if there is anymore info I can provide about this problem
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommand you to follow this [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view#0) from the documentation, which shows how to use Room properly.

You will initialize your `ViewModel` class inside the activities where you want to access your data,

```java
private ViewModel mViewModel;
```

give it a value inside the `onCreate()` method of your activity

```java
mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModel.class);
```

and the `ViewModel` will call the `getDatabase()` method below inside its constructor

```java
static RoomDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (RoomDatabase.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            RoomDatabase.class, "database")
// Prepopulate from a .db file
                            .createFromAsset("database/database.db")
// Or from code --> check this step from the codelab
// https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view#12
                            // .addCallback(sRoomDatabaseCallback)
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
```